# Special Character "/" as Return Address

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This code is in an ActionResult function in a Controller, when the return url is:

```
RedirectToLocal("/");
```

What does "/" mean?
Couldn't find any documentations for RedirectToLocal.

**Edit 1**

Okay, found the definition of RedirectToLocal in the same project, so its not a built-in function like I thought:

```
    private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            //If no returnURL is stored
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Give some more information about your problem.

Comment: Press `F12` on `RedirectToLocal` in Visual Studio and you'll have a better idea of where it comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RedirectToLocal` method is a helper method that makes sure that the URL for the redirect really is a local address. It helps you to protect your site from cross site scripting attacks, where an URL entered by a user could go to some harmful site.

Redirecting to `/` will take you to the default page of the site. This is definitely a local URL, so `RedirectToLocal("/")` does the same as `Redirect("/")`.

Comment: What do you mean by the "default page of the site"? You mean the current controller's Index page?

Comment: @MVC_noob: It's the root page of the site. The same page that you get to when you browse to just the domain name without anything after it. What that is depends on how you have set up your routes.

Comment: Makes sense. I guess this is a shorthand for "website_name.com/" <---    "/"

Comment: @MVC_noob There are different types of URL's. **Absolute URL**: Starts with the protocol, ie. `http://www.google.com/index.html`. **Protocol-relative URL**: Starts with two slashes, ie. `//www.google.com/index.html`. **Path-relative URL**: Starts with one slash, ie. `/index.html`. **Page-relative URL**: Starts with the page name or dot(s), ie. `index.html` or `./index.html`. **Fragment**: Starts with # and won't work in your case since it isn't a real URL but meant for the client-side only, ie. `#top`.

Answer (score 0):

The `RedirectToLocal` method is created in the default MVC template in the `AccountController`. It was a method built by the template and is *by default* local to that controller. This is often then copied into a base controller to be leveraged by other controllers.

The purpose in the `AccountController` was to allow you to redirect to a relative URL after authenticating (i.e. returning to where you came from). The value of the `returnUrl` would be in the form of `/{controller}/{action}/{id}`. The specific line you're looking at will redirect to the *default* controller/action defined in your routing table (this is most generally `Home/Index`).

Comment: Really! I thought it was a built-in function like View(). MY bad.